# C# - input method for strings from file

Tags: c#, string, methods, input, filestream

Ok. I'm a beginner programmer and am having trouble getting an input method to work in a .dll I'm building. Here is the method:

```
public void Input(StreamReader fileIn)
{
  string lineIn;

  while ((lineIn = fileIn.ReadLine()) != null)
    this.Add(Double.Parse(lineIn));
}
```

I keep getting a red-line (I'm using Visual Studio 2013) on the `this.Add(Double.parse(lineIn));` line.

Any ideas?

Comment: At least hover over the line!? VS will give you a clue. I suspect the problem is with `this.Add()` (what is `this`?) as opposed to what you are trying to parse (a string should be fine - and if it's not, you won't know yet anyway until runtime).

Comment: Can you give us the specific error message?

Comment: What is `this.Add`, do you have a `List` in your class, `List<Double>`, place its name, instead of `this`

Comment: What id `this` mean? are you working on a some kind of a collection?

Comment: You really need to tell us the Error message that is being told to you by VS. That would help us solve the problem.

Comment: @PseudoNym01 - "the best overloaded method match for 'LibStringList.StringList.Add(string)' has some invalid arguments"

Comment: @huMptyduMpty - yes, I'm working on a .dll that ties to a main .cs file. Sorry if I'm not describing right, folks. I've just started C# programming a few months ago. Still very new at this. :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take your code:

```
public void Input(StreamReader fileIn)
{
  string lineIn;

  while ((lineIn = fileIn.ReadLine()) != null)
    this.Add(Double.Parse(lineIn));
}
```

change this line:

```
 this.Add(Double.Parse(lineIn));
```

to this:

```
this.Add(Double.Parse(lineIn).ToString());
```

Double.Parse takes an input and converts it to a double, you have a list of strings. To add to that list you need to take the double and convert it to a string.

Comment: Thanks, PseudoNym01! That did it. So the .ToString converts a data type to string? I'm still trying to remember all of my IDE tools, data types, etc.

Comment: Yep, ToString() does exactly what it says, converts to a string. Its a pretty helpful function that is available to almost every Object in the .NET framework see here for reference: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.object.tostring.aspx